# AngularJS: Modify transcluded attribute key in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, directive, transclusion

Given:

```
<radio radio-name="login"></radio>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('radio', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            radioName: '@'
        },
        template: '<label></label>',
        link: function ( ... ) {}
    }
});
```

I want the resulting markup to be:

```
<label data-radio-name="login" ...>
```

Instead of what is currently outputted:

```
<label radio-name="login" ...>
```

I want to keep 'radio-name' on the initial markup so you can tell it is a custom directive, but I want the resulting transcluded/replaced  to have the semantic data attribute 'data-radio-name'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `radioName` mode from `@` to `=` and set template empty:

```
template: '<label data-radio-name=""></label>'
```

Something like:

```
.directive('radio', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            radioName: '='
        },
        template: '<label data-radio-name=""></label>',
        link: function ( ) {}
    }
});
```

Output:

```
<label data-radio-name="login"></label>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/774/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok, great that worked! What about if I want the <label> to not retain the attributes? So it would output just <label><input name="login"></label> instead of <label data-radio-name="login"><input name="login"></label>?